# Function printing but not working into an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

We are having troubles trying to insert multiple values generated from a function into an array.
When we print the function using a string and we copy the results manually it works but when we try to make it work using the string into an array it doesn't.

```
<?php 

function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'm/d/Y' ) {

$current = strtotime( $first );
$last = strtotime( $last );

while( $current <= $last ) {

    $dates .= "'" . date( $format, $current) . "', ";
    $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
}

return $dates;
} 

$all_dates = dateRange( '01/20/1999', '01/23/1999'); 

echo $all_dates; /* PRINTS ALL DATES BETWEEN TWO DATES: '01/20/1999', '01/21/1999', '01/22/1999', '01/23/1999', */

query_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'bbdd',
'meta_query' => array(
    $location,
    array(
        'key' => 'date',
        'value' => array($all_dates), /*  DOESN'T WORK. INSTEAD, IF WE COPY THE RESULT OF "echo $all_dates;" MANUALLY, IT DOES WORK */
    ),
)
) );

?>
```

Comment: When you do array($all_dates) in your code, the result is not an array with all of the dates as separate values. The result is an array with ONE value that contains the returned string. I.e., not array('01/20/1999', '01/21/1999') but instead array("'01/20/1999', '01/21/1999'").

Comment: Thanks for your helpful explanation. We understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a string, not an array, in the function.

```
function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'm/d/Y' ) {

    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date($format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

That will return an array.

Then, in your mysql query:

```
'value'   => $all_dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put it in an array in the first place:

```
<?php

function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'm/d/Y' ) {
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {

            $dates[] = date($format, $current);
            $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
} 

?>
```